# CORS - localhost as allowed origin in production

Tags: rest, security, http, webserver, cors

Occasionally when troubleshooting bugs in production, it would be convenient to be able to hit our production REST server from my local dev environment. But i'm concerned that adding localhost to allowed origins would be a security risk. Searches have yielded conflicting information. Are my concerns valid? Why or why not?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I'm assuming you have

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost
```

The risk is that any services running on a user's machine could effectively bypass the [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) for your site.

So if you have a REST URL such as

```
https://example.com/User/GetUserDetails
```

A malicious or compromised service running on the user's computer could make that request via the user's browser and then grab details about the user, because their authentication cookie will be passed with the request.

Now, you could argue that a malicious service running on the user's computer could just grab the authentication cookie from their browser directly and then make the request itself. However, if the service has some flaws of its own (say XSS), this could allow another site to compromise the user via your REST service (`evil.example.org --XSS-> localhost -CORS-> example.com/User/GetUserDetails`).

Another scenario that could put you at risk if the user is running a local reverse proxy to access something. This would enable the target site to compromise the user through yours, should that target site be malicious or be compromised. This is because the user would be accessing the target site with a domain of `localhost`.

If you really need to do this I suggest you have a special developer account for your REST service that when accessed adds the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://localhost` header to your requests only. That way, you are not putting other users at risk because you know you are only running the front-end server only at `https://localhost` so you cannot be compromised by your open CORS setting.

Another way may be to use something like `noonewouldusethis2859282.localhost` for your local copy of the front-end. Then you can safely add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://noonewouldusethis2859282.localhost` header because nobody else would use this and would be safe from CORS attacks.

Comment: @Eliran - Reverting your edits as they change the meaning of my answer. Please see https://security.stackexchange.com/a/97938/8340 - CORS is about reading data, not submitting data (i.e. CSRF). CORS _could_ of course allow a CSRF token to be read if configured incorrectly, however, this is not what I'm conveying here (`GetUserDetails` is a read operation, not write).

Comment: oh, sorry for stepping on your toes, i innocently thought that the semantics was wrong. thanx for the clarification :)

Comment: Where do I put these two lines? Do I scratch them into my wall?

Comment: I'm not sure that `noonewouldusethis2859282.localhost` is an effective control. If you have the value in your Access-Control-Allow-Origin header, then it can be read by an attacker and used just like localhost would be. Sounds like an attempt at "Security through Obscurity" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity), which is not usually a reliable method of protection.

Comment: @BrianV It doesn't matter if the attacker knows that value as that hostname is under control of the user, not the attacker. In an XSS attack, the attacker can retrieve the host name anyway (`document.domain`). The attacker would not be in a position to spoof that, assuming that the local service does not respond to wildcard virtual hosts, which means you could be compromised in other ways too.

Comment: I don't understand the XSS security problem from the description above. Could you expand it?

As for the second scenario, it doesn't sound possible assuming the target site is only available over TLS. Sure, a local proxy could proxy the raw TCP connection, but it can't decrypt the HTTP payload, change the Origin header, and re-encrypt. The level of compromise required to do that is essentially complete and CORS cannot help at that point.

Comment: @StephenCrosby Say `App C` trusts `App B` via CORS. `App B` is running on `localhost` and `C` outputs `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000`. Therefore, `B` can make requests to `C` and read responses via the browser. However, if `B` contains an XSS flaw, `A` can compromise `B` via the XSS flaw and get data from `C`, since `C` trusts `B` which now has malicious requests from `A`. As for your second question, decryption is not needed if CORS grants access. The browser sees the responses in plain text since the browser automatically decrypts responses sent from an app over TLS.

Answer (score 29):

There is no security concern with adding localhost to your CORS setup in production.

By adding something like:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:3000
```

The browser is now allowed to make calls from localhost:3000 to your service, bypassing [Same Origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Any web developer can now create a webpage running from their local machine to make a call to your API, which is useful for your team. However, localhost is not a [publicly routable address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost) - You can't share a link to http://localhost:3000. Remember, CORS is only a security measure for web browsers making calls to your site. Anyone can still call your endpoint via server to server calls (or a script). However, you should **avoid**:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This will make your site available to every website. Instead, lock down your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to the sites that need it. Unfortunately, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` only takes a single value, so you have to process HOST request server side and return valid ones ([more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653308/access-control-allow-origin-multiple-origin-domains)).

## Authentication when calling a CORS endpoint

When you make a CORS request which requires authentication, you should be adding an `Authorization` header to the call, and not passing cookies -
 [fetch does this by default](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch). Thus any calls made to a CORs end point would be made via javascript adding a token to the header that it only has for that session. If you do store the token via a cookie or localstorage, note that its only accessible from that domain ([more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies)). Your production endpoint and localhost will not have the same cookies and shared localstorage.

## Disabling CORS in Chrome

Lastly, you can make CORS request from Chrome to any site by starting Chrome with `--disable-web-security` ([more info](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2014/08/bypass-cors-errors-testing-apis-locally/)).

Lastly, Google Chrome only allows service workers to run on secure websites and http://localhost. If you choose to create a local.example.com for development, you'll need to create an SSL cert and do all the configuration on your local machine to get that running. I recommend just using http://localhost:XXXX.